# GCEventViewController not disabling UIKit controls (tvOS)

Tags: uikit, tvos

I am attempting to implement a pause menu in my SpriteKit game, however when the user hits the menu button it goes back to the previous view. I am using GCEventViewController to attempt to disable UIKit interaction, but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/ControllingInputontvOS/ControllingInputontvOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013276-CH7-DontLinkElementID_13) you need to subclass your ViewController from

```
 GCEventViewController
```

and set it's property

```
controllerUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: `false` is actually the default value, so simply subclassing should work.

Comment: bio, yes but obviously DaveMoore had it set to true.

Comment: It isn't working for me either. I've subclassed GCEventViewController and I'm explicitly setting controllerUserInteractionEnabled to false on viewDidLoad but the MENU button still sends me back to the previous view controller :/

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the Apple Developer Forums,
[Stop Menu Button going back to previous screen](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/85122#85122)

All my view controllers are simple inheriting from UIViewController (so the Swift code can be shared with iOS), and in the view controller where I have my game scene, I've added this property and this code,

```
let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "menuButtonAction:")
    menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
}
func menuButtonAction(sender: NSObject) {
    pauseGame()
    self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}
func startGame() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}
```

Basically, when I start the game I intercept the Menu button press to pause my game, but while in pause, I remove the tap gesture recognizer, so if you press Menu again, you'll abort the game and then move back to the previous screen (if you decide to continue, then I re-add the menuPressRecognizer).

Hope this helps.